# Rotate image via javascript using CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I'm doing a clock in javascript and I am not sure this way is the best way to rotate the pointers.

Is this ok, or is there a better way?

```
// browser vendors
var browsers = [
    'webkit',
    'Moz',
    'ms',
    'O',
    ''];

// function to move the pointers
function moveMe(el, unit) {
    var deg = unit * 360 / 60;
    browsers.each(function (b) {
        el.style[b + 'Transform'] = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    });
}

// function to check the time
function checkTime() {
    var date = new Date();
    var seconds = date.getSeconds();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var hours = date.getHours();
    moveMe(sPointer, seconds);
    !seconds && moveMe(mPointer, minutes);
    !minutes && moveMe(hPointer, hours);
}
```

The fiddle I'm playing with is [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/9ZY6u/).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your code use `Array.each()` method, which is a non-standard Javascript method, added by Mootools. I would rather use a standard loop, in order to keep a *vanilla* JS code.

Then, instead of setting all properties every time, you should test which properties are supported by the browser and set them accordingly.

Finally, since you are moving minutes only when `!seconds` (i.e. `seconds == 0`), the clock initialization is a bit weird. On page load, you should always move minutes and hours.

Comment: Thanks for feedback! I do initialization on __[my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ZY6u/)__. About the `.each()` I have more mootools but sure, a vanilla loop is better. Good idea to detect browser... About the rotation itself, is that the best way to do it? By setting style on the image?

Comment: That's indeed the most straightforward solution. Otherwise, you'll need to use HTML5 Canvas API.

Comment: For reference, there is an [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method that is standard JavaScript (ES 5.1).

Comment: I disagree with the `.each` comment. If you're using a framework you can write code for the framework

Answer (score 1):

In GCC, if you write `!seconds && moveMe(mPointer, minutes);` and compile with `-Wall` you get this warning:

```
[Warning] value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
```

I know this is not C, but the problem is the same and I can't see why you don't explicitly write `if`.

Comment: +1 for pointing out a possible bug. Is this also the case if the first value is not negated with `!`? Because this is a common practise in javascript